# How to call a pure virtual base class method implemented by subclass function?

Tags: c++, qt

I have two classes: `AbstractClass` and `SubClass`.

This is basically my code (well, just some example code):

### `abstractclass.h`

```
class AbstractClass
{
public:
    AbstractClass();
    void doSomething();

protected:
    virtual void implementMe() = 0;
    int a;
};
```

### `abstractclass.cpp`

```
#include "abstractclass.h"
AbstractClass::AbstractClass(){}

void AbstractClass::doSomething()
{
    implementMe();  // compiler error: "implementMe() was not declared in this scope"
    a = 0;          // same compiler error here...
}
```

### `subclass.h`

```
#include "abstractclass.h"
class SubClass : public AbstractClass
{
public:
    SubClass();

protected:
    void implementMe();
};
```

### `subclass.cpp`

```
#include "subclass.h"
SubClass::SubClass() {}

void SubClass::implementMe()
{
    // do some stuff
}
```

In the `AbstractClass`, however, I keep getting a compiler error (for the virtual function as well as for the class variable):

> implementMe() was not declared in this scope

The only way I found to get rid of this was to use forward-declaration:

```
void implementMe();
AbstractClass::doSomething()
{
    implementMe();
}
```

I cannot believe that this is the correct way, though?

Thanks!

## EDIT:

Ok, as my conceptual understanding of subclassing in `C++` doesn't seem to be totally wrong (see the comments), I'm gonna share some of my original source code. Hopefully this will help to indentify the error.

This is my abstract / base class:

### `abstractenvironment.h`

```
#ifndef ABSTRACTENVIRONMENT_H
#define ABSTRACTENVIRONMENT_H

#include <QObject>

class AbstractEnvironment : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    AbstractEnvironment(QObject *parent = 0);

protected:
    virtual void process() = 0;
    quint32 counter;

private slots:
  void handleTimeout();
};
#endif // ABSTRACTENVIRONMENT_H
```

### `abstractenvironment.cpp`

```
#include "abstractenvironment.h"
#include <QTimer>

QTimer *myTimer;

AbstractEnvironment::AbstractEnvironment(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    myTimer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(myTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &AbstractEnvironment::handleTimeout);
    myTimer->start(1);
    counter = 0;
}

void handleTimeout()
{
    process();
    counter++;
}
```

And this is my subclass:

### `environment.h`

```
#ifndef ENVIRONMENT_H
#define ENVIRONMENT_H

#include "abstractenvironment.h"
class Environment : public AbstractEnvironment
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Environment(Controller *controller, QObject *parent = 0);

protected:
    void process();
};
#endif // ENVIRONMENT_H
```

### `environment.cpp`

```
#include "environment.h"

Environment::Environment(Controller *controller, QObject *parent) :
    AbstractEnvironment(controller, parent) {}

void Environment::process()
{
    // do something
}
```

PS: I've learned from the first part of this question and tried to compile the source code above inside Qt with MinGW. I get exactly two error messages (as expected):

```
..\untitled\abstractenvironment.cpp: In function 'void handleTimeout()':
..\untitled\abstractenvironment.cpp:17:13: error: 'process' was not declared in this scope
..\untitled\abstractenvironment.cpp:18:5: error: 'counter' was not declared in this scope
```

In case you want to try it yourself, I've zipped the Qt project and [uploaded](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x2r6jxhk3arg070/Qt_project.zip?dl=0) it to my Dropbox (of course I will remove this file at some point but the code is exactly the same as in the post above --> it's just for the sake of convenience, so you don't have to copy-paste it yourself)

Comment: `implementMe();` inside `AbstractClass::doSomething()` tries to call `AbstractClass::implementMe()`

Comment: I don't think it is the issue, but you don't have a `;` after the class definitions.

Comment: @Creris And what should be wrong about this?

Comment: You have no return type on `doSomething`.

Comment: @Creris: Yes, that's what I thought already, but the question is how I could tell the compiler I want to call the function implemented by the subclass'? I've tried `this.doSomething()` and `SubClass::doSomething()` already but neither of these worked.

Comment: @mozzbozz What compiler are you using? VS2013 compiles this code without errors (after adding `;` and fixing return type of `doSomething()`).

Comment: @Cameron: It's a typo. My real code is much more complex, so I couldn't share it here. Fixed it (and double checked I haven't done the same mistake in my real code). Also fixed the typo found by @clcto (I've actually never noticed that there must be a `;` at the end of class declarations -> it was always added by my IDE automatically; so thank you, just learned something new ;)).

Comment: @mozzbozz: With that typo fixed (and also the incorrect name for the `SubClass` constructor), the code you've posted compiles for me. Please post code that gives the error you're asking about, with no other errors.

Comment: @Paul: I'm using MinGW on Windows in a Qt-project. I don't want to trust MSVC though as it is well known for not following conventions and while researching about this compiler error I've read about a few things about subclassing the MSVC allows, although they are not compliant to the c++ language specification...

Comment: @mozzbozz Builds for me with MinGW 4.8.0.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: 1) Which compiler did you use? 2) Ok, I'm gonna have a look at the code again anyway (knowing I was probably looking at the wrong spot) and eventually update my question with some original code.

Comment: @Paul: Ok, thanks! I'm gonna need to have another look into it...

Comment: @mozzbozz: GCC. Here's a demonstration with everything in one file (for the benefit of the online compiler): http://ideone.com/9QU8tS. It works just as well with your file structure.

Comment: GCC 4.8.1 on IDEOne compiles and runs this successfully: http://ideone.com/KbUGnK

Comment: Oh thanks, didn't know this website. Seems to be a good playground for code testing!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: You just changed your question. So I can't tell if your original text was your actual source code or not. Good rule of thumb, paste your actual code rather than paraphrase it (then de-identify or reduce it if needed).

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

```
implementMe();  // compiler error: "implementMe() was not declared in this scope"
```

That is because doSomething() isn't declared properly in AbstractClass. You "declared" it in the base class with:

```
doSomething();
```

The compiler doesn't recognize AbstractClass::doSomething() out of line definition so nothing inside the implementation is resolved to the class scope.

Change that to:

```
void doSomething();
```

just like in your derived class.

and

```
AbstractClass::doSomething()
{
    implementMe();
}
```

to

```
void AbstractClass::doSomething()
{
    implementMe();
}
```

UPDATE:

```
void handleTimeout()
{
    process();
    counter++;
}
```

is a global function. That isn't the class implementation. It should be:

```
void AbstractClass::handleTimeout()
{
    process();
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry, this was a mistake, because I paraphrased my code (see the comments on my question). However, this would have lead to some different compiler error. I thought paraphrasing the code would be better as it is much easier to understand and I thought my mistake was some conceptual misunderstanding rather than a "normal" bug...

Comment: Something is afoot. Your code is correct (at least compiles in my head). Look elsewhere for the problem. If your prototype is different from the out of line defination you will get that error.

Comment: I've just updated the question to contain the original code, just as you've suggested.

Comment: See my revision after UPDATE section. You didn't qualify your handleTimeout() function with class scope, so it is a global.

Comment: Thank you very much! Small mistake, huge impact :/ Such things happen when one is new to C++ and coming from Java/C... Finally works :) I've read over it so many times without noticing now :/

Answer (score 2):

In `abstractenvironment.cpp` you define `void handleTimeout()`, which is non-member function and does not relate to `AbstractEnvironment` class. Thus, it doesn't look for `AbstractEnvironment::process()` and `AbstractEnvironment::counter`, but for `::process()` and `::counter` instead (which are not declared, hence the error).

Change it to `void AbstractEnvironment::handleTimeout()` and it should compile.